# How to run Forloop under a SECOND without altering the loops

Tags: c#

I am required to run this forloop in under a SECOND without making any changes 
to the loops and the forloop as a whole.

```
var someLongDataString = "";
const int sLen = 30, loops = 50000; 
var source = new string('X', sLen);

Console.WriteLine();
for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) 
{
    someLongDataString += source;
}
```

**EDIT:** the restriction doesn't apply to `someLongDataString += source;`

Comment: _"without making any changes to the loops and the forloop as a whole"_ - does that apply to the `someLongDataString += source;` statement?

Comment: Easy; get a faster computer

Comment: Replace `const int sLen = 30, loops = 50000; ` with `const int sLen = 0, loops = 0;`. Runs instantaneously and we haven't touched the loop.

Comment: @Rob ;) well you did actually, you ultimately changed the number of iterations of the loops

Comment: @MickyD without changing the number of loops which is 50000 and no it doesn't apply to "someLongDataString += source;".

Comment: @Sizwe thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

As I indicated in the comment, it implies a change to the statement within the loop.

Your code:

[image]

This code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someLongDataString = "";
        var builder = new StringBuilder(); // <---- use a StringBuilder instead
        const int sLen = 30, loops = 50000;
        var source = new string('X', sLen);

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Console.WriteLine();
        for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            //someLongDataString += source;
            builder.Append(source);
        }

        someLongDataString = builder.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

After:

[image]

### Why so fast?

Performing en-mass concatenations to a string is terribly inefficient sadly as new objects are being created, remember `string` is *immutable*.  `StringBuilder` isn't and in addition, uses a pre-allocated buffer to accommodate potential additions.  So instead of allocating for each and every call, it only restructures it's buffer once it becomes filled.

MSDN has this to say on `StringBuilder`:

> For routines that perform extensive string manipulation (**such as apps that modify a string numerous times in a loop**), modifying a string repeatedly can exact a **significant performance penalty**. The alternative is to use StringBuilder, which is a mutable string class. Mutability means that once an instance of the class has been created, it can be modified by appending, removing, replacing, or inserting characters. A StringBuilder object maintains a **buffer to accommodate expansions** to the string. New data is appended to the buffer if room is available; otherwise, a new, larger buffer is allocated, data from the original buffer is copied to the new buffer, and the new data is then appended to the new buffer. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)

Pay particular note to this too:

> Although the StringBuilder class generally offers better performance than the String class, **you should not automatically replace String with StringBuilder** whenever you want to manipulate strings. Performance depends on the **size** of the string, the amount of **memory** to be allocated for the new string, the **system** on which your app is executing, and the **type** of operation. You should be prepared to test your app to determine whether StringBuilder actually offers a significant performance improvement. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use string builder. But this requires a change with in the forloop

```
var starttime = DateTime.Now;
var someLongDataString = new StringBuilder(100000);
const int sLen = 30, loops = 50000;
var source = new string('X', sLen);


Console.WriteLine();
for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++)
{
    someLongDataString.Append(source);
}

Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - starttime).Milliseconds);
Console.ReadLine();
```